# Alternative to AzureBlob File Copy on VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I have used the AzureBlob File Copy task on VSTS to distribute a client library to azure blob storage that SPA clients consume libraries from aswell as stylesheets.

It looks like AzureBlob File Copy do not set content headers on files and therefore the clients cant consume the content properly.

Is there any other tasks that can resolve this issue or what is the extent of making a custom task that can upload and set content types properly. ect js to application/javascript and css to text/css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own task in c# from some existing code I had.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using CommandLine;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using SInnovations.VSTeamServices.TaskBuilder.Attributes;
using SInnovations.VSTeamServices.TaskBuilder.AzureResourceManager.ResourceTypes;
using SInnovations.VSTeamServices.TaskBuilder.ConsoleUtils;
using SInnovations.VSTeamServices.TaskBuilder.ResourceTypes;
using SInnovations.VSTeamServices.TaskBuilder.Tasks;

namespace AzureBlobFileCopy
{

    public class ConnectedServiceRelation : PropertyRelation<ProgramOptions, ServiceEndpoint>
    {
        public ConnectedServiceRelation()
            : base(k => k.ConnectedServiceName)
        {

        }
    }

    [ResourceType(TaskInputType = "pickList")]
    public class ARMListKey : IConsoleReader<ProgramOptions>, IConsoleExecutor<ProgramOptions>
    {
        public void OnConsoleParsing(Parser parser, string[] args, ProgramOptions options, PropertyInfo info)
        {
            Id = args[Array.IndexOf(args, "--storage") + 1];
        }

        public void Execute(ProgramOptions options)
        {
            var http = options.ConnectedServiceName.GetAuthorizedHttpClient("https://management.azure.com/");

            var keys = http.PostAsync($"https://management.azure.com{Id}/listKeys?api-version=2016-01-01", new StringContent(string.Empty)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var keysObj = JObject.Parse(keys.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());

            Account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(Id.Split('/').Last(), keysObj.SelectTokens("$.keys[*].value").First().ToString()), true);
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public CloudStorageAccount Account { get; set; }

    }

    [ConnectedServiceRelation(typeof(ConnectedServiceRelation))]
    [EntryPoint("Uploading to $(storage)")]
    [Group(DisplayName = "Output", isExpanded = true, Name = "output")]
    public class ProgramOptions
    {

        [Display(ShortName = "source", Name = "Copy Path", Description = "The files that should be copied", ResourceType = typeof(GlobPath))]
        public GlobPath Source { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Azure Subscription", ShortName = "ConnectedServiceName", ResourceType = typeof(ServiceEndpoint), Description = "Azure Service Principal to obtain tokens from")]
        public ServiceEndpoint ConnectedServiceName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ArmResourceIdPicker("Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts", "2016-01-01")]
        [Display(ShortName = "storage", Name = "Storage Account", Description = "The storage account to copy files to", ResourceType = typeof(ARMListKey))]
        public ARMListKey StorageAccount { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Container Name")]
        [Option("container", Required = true)]
        public string ContainerName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prefix for uploaded data")]
        [Option("prefix")]
        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fail if files Exists")]
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        [Option("failOnExists")]
        public bool FailIfFilesExist { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Storage Container Uri", GroupName = "output")]
        [Option("StorageContainerUri")]
        public string StorageContainerUri { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Storage Container SAS token", GroupName = "output")]
        [Option("StorageContainerSASToken")]
        public string StorageContainerSASToken
        {
            get; set;
        }


        [Display(Name = "Verbose", Description = "Write out each file thats uploaded")]
        [Option("Verbose")]
        public bool Verbose { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private static readonly ManualResetEvent runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
     //       args = new[] { "--build" };
#endif
            ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = ServicePointManager.DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit * 100;

            try
            {

                RunAsync(ConsoleHelper.ParseAndHandleArguments<ProgramOptions>($"Finding and uploading data", args),
                    cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();

            }
            finally
            {
                runCompleteEvent.Set();
            }

        }

        private static async Task RunAsync(ProgramOptions ops, CancellationToken cannelcationtoken)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Uploading data at {ops.Source} to {ops.StorageAccount.Account.BlobEndpoint} using {ops.Prefix} as prefix in {ops.ContainerName}");

            var client = ops.StorageAccount.Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var container = client.GetContainerReference(ops.ContainerName);

            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            if (ops.FailIfFilesExist)
            {
                var uploads = ops.Source.MatchedFiles()
                    .Select(file => Path.Combine(ops.Prefix, file.Substring(ops.Source.Root.Length).TrimStart('/', '\\')).Replace("\\", "/"))
                    .ToLookup(k=>k);

                foreach(var file in container.ListBlobs(ops.Prefix, true).OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name))
                {
                    if (uploads.Contains(file))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("##vso[task.logissue type=error] File Exists: " + file);
                        throw new Exception("File exists: " + file);
                    }
                }


            }



            var actionBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Tuple<string, CloudBlockBlob, TimeSpan>>(async (string file) =>
               {
                   var filestopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                   using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
                   {
                       var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.Combine(ops.Prefix,file.Substring(ops.Source.Root.Length).TrimStart('/','\\')).Replace("\\","/"));
                       blob.Properties.ContentType = Constants.GetContentType(file);

                       using (var writeable = await blob.OpenWriteAsync())
                       {
                           await fileStream.CopyToAsync(writeable);
                       }
                       return new Tuple<string, CloudBlockBlob, TimeSpan>(file, blob, filestopWatch.Elapsed);
                   }

               }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 64 });

            var i = 0;
            var completed = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, CloudBlockBlob, TimeSpan>>((blob) =>
             {
                 if (ops.Verbose)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {blob.Item1} to {blob.Item2.Name} completed in {blob.Item3}");
                 }

                 Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
             });

            actionBlock.LinkTo(completed, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
            foreach (var file in ops.Source.MatchedFiles())
            {

                await actionBlock.SendAsync(file);
            }

            actionBlock.Complete();

            await completed.Completion;

            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {i} files to {container.Name}{ops.Prefix} in {stopWatch.Elapsed}");


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ops.StorageContainerUri))
            {
                TaskHelper.SetVariable(ops.StorageContainerUri, container.Uri.ToString());

            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ops.StorageContainerSASToken))
            {
                TaskHelper.SetVariable(ops.StorageContainerSASToken, container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
                {
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Add | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write
                }),
                     true);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AzureBlob File Copy uses AzCopy behind the scenes so how about adding `/SetContentType` argument as value in Additional Arguments field?

I believe this will get AzCopy to set content-type based on file extension

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#specify-the-mime-content-type-of-a-destination-blob

Comment: good catch. This is the easiest way. I will keep my answer around as it shows how one could easily customize if needed more flexibility then standard filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to set headers on the files. First copy the files and than use an Azure Powershell task to set the headers. Or you can just do the upload and set the headers directly from Powershell.